# Couldn't find the binary git

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I am new to react-native.

After I changed  `"rn-nodeify":"10.3.0"`  to  `package.json` under `devDependencies` and run `npm install`

[my project](https://github.com/nomoreboredom/rn-node-js)

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ardailgaz/wanna-some-node-js-core-modules-on-mobile-3e047511b915)

If I run this command `npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest` then this `npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest` the below error occured.

```
C:\Users\mahima\Desktop\react-native\rn-node-js-master>npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> NodeJSExampleApp@0.0.1 postinstall
> ./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install --hack

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\mahima\Desktop\react-native\rn-node-js-master
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c 
./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install --hack

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mahima\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-29T06_39_05_153Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\mahima\Desktop\react-native\rn-node-js-master>
```

How can I solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this in package.json ?

```
"rn-nodeify":"10.3.0"
```

or any specific version which you want, usually package.json expects :

```
[packageName]:[version number]
```

alternative, why dont you try installing like this from terminal ?

```
npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest
```

Comment: If I add `"rn-nodeif":"10.3.0"` in package.json it comes like this `npm ERR! 404  'rn-nodeif@10.3.0' is not in this registry.`

Comment: sorry missed a Y, please check updated @Jeeva

Comment: its rn-nodeify , missed a y, my bad

Comment: @Jeeva updated answer

Comment: same error occured I edited my question. Can you explain how to install `rn-nodeif` from begeing ? please !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247639/discussion-between-gaurav-roy-and-jeeva).

Comment: sorry, couldnt help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the GIT installed on your device and accessible globally. Try to type `git --version` in the CMD. If it returned that the command is not recognized and GIT already installed, then you need to add it to the PATH environment variable and make sure to try the command using a new CMD session

Comment: First understand my question.